# How do .razor files behave as both HTML and CS files and how could I recreate this behaviour

Tags: c#, html, css, razor, compilation

I want to make a library that is to CSS what Razor is to HTML. I've planned out my general progress path, but I'm not sure how I can have these files act as both CSS and CS. For example, in a `.razor` file, you have access to a `@code` block. This code block is essentially the `.razor` file's CS class, and it has access to shared methods from other CS classes. You can also extend this to a separate CS file using the same class name with the `partial` keyword. Shared methods in either of these files will be accessible to other classes and/or `.razor` files.

So, how can I make a CSS variant of this? I understand that `.razor` files automatically inherit from a class provided by the `AspNetCore` libraries, but how does this happen, and how can I do this? How can I use CSS in this file, and how can I add the use of CS to it? Since it'll be for use with a `.razor` project, it'll use `@` the same way as `.razor` to use keywords in the file, but how can I do that? This is a lot of questions, so let's break it into a list.

1. Create a way to add the use of CS that interferes in no way with CSS. Like Razor, if you have a working CSS file it should be as simple as to change the extension so it is recognised as a CS/CSS file.
2. That, however, brings another question. How can I recognise these files as the CS/CSS variants? The extension will be changed from `.css`, but that doesn't magically fix this, so what does?
3. How will this be able to compile into a `.css` file that can be used on a website, but also be able to be modified with CS, similar to how you can make JavaScript calls like `element.style` to modify whatever style it is as required.
4. I know I'll need a class/interface for the CS/CSS file to inherit from, but what does this class need, and how can I apply it? It'll need the ability to store CSS data obviously, but what else? Does it need extra virtual methods like `OnInitialized` in Razor?
5. This isn't a question per se, but rather a *"If you have a question then ask it and if I want to then it'll be added here"* kinda reminder.

This is a lot to ask, and a lot to break down and focus on, but I'm sure it'll get there. Eventually..

Or you know, maybe not? Who knows, maybe someone will have an answer straight away, or maybe I'll be here waiting for the motivation to look through the `AspNetCore` source code (thank god for open source frameworks) and find even a single answer. Either way, all help is appreciated, and all criticism is as well, as long as it's constructive. That's all for now.